# QLineEdit doubleValidator starting with point

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit

I have a UI with a QLineEdit which only accepts float/double values with the help of a QDoubleValidator.
It only accepts values if I enter a leading number like: 0.234. But I'd prefer to be able to enter values directly without a leading number like .234. Unfortunately the QDoubleValidator does not accept a leading point. Is there any way to archive my goal with the help of the validator, or do I have to check every entered character myself? I'm using Qt 5.9.1 on Windows10.

```
QDoubleValidator* doubleValidator = new QDoubleValidator();
QLineEdit* lineEdit = new QLineEdit(frame);
lineEdit->setValidator(doubleValidator);
vbox->addWidget(lineEdit);
```

Comment: show your code.

Comment: What version of qt are you using? This works fine for me (with or without a leading dot) when using either qt-4.8.7 or qt-5.10.0. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, it is the first time I post something, will read the link, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `QDoubleValidator` is pretty limited, but you can use `QRegExpValidator` to get what you want with a regex describing a number, depending on the notation you expect.

```
// non-scientific floating-point numbers
QRegExp rx("[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+");
QRegExpValidator v(rx, 0);
QString s;
s = ".123";
v.validate(s, 0);    // Returns Acceptable
```

This is much more extendable, and allows you to abstract it to any condition, with basic regular expression knowledge.

Comment: Did you actually test `QDoubleValidator`? It works fine for me.

Comment: Yes, I checked the QDoubleValidator and it does not accept a leading ".", at least on my machine here.

Comment: What is your version of Qt and OS?

Comment: Qt 5.9.1 on Windows10.

Comment: Tried QDoubleValidator on Ubuntu 14.04 with qt4.8.7 and it also works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for testing, so it seems to be a Window only problem, maybe others can approve it?

Comment: @haggikrey I just got around to testing it, and it works here. My guess would be a locale problem then, since the double validation is tightly tied to the locale.